# How to convert different file into .doc file using php

Tags: php

If i click the button *convert* and file should be converted into .doc file through php. if i have file of pdf in database , so how can it be display in word file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be more precise but here some hint if your try to convert a PDF to a Doc file.

Depending of the file type, but using an API you can convert file format to another one. Eg : Cloudconvert has a PDF to Doc converter by eg ( https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-doc ).

It has a cost but if you do it on you own (possible with a Windows server) it will cost a lot more.

I use Cloud Convert on one of my project : it works well, but it depends a lot of the source file.

Comment: Do it by yourself will be really painful, you mai in all case use an API or a binary who will do the job. So pure PHP code isn't the solution.